# Switch (or remove) class name on a RichFaces 4 component (so I can use themeroller)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, richfaces

Ok, let me preface this by saying that I've read the following:

[Stackoverflow:how can i remove the css classes from a richfaces component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455018/how-can-i-remove-the-css-classes-from-a-richfaces-component)

HOWEVER, I am using version 4 and this appears to apply to v3.x.  I'm wondering if anything might have changed.

Here's my situation, we're using jquery and jquery ui for a large portion of our project.  This project already has a ton of work done on it so it's not feasible to switch to a different framework.  As I'm sure you can understand, we are using themeroller themes to generate our look and feel.

In a couple of places, we've elected to use some RichFaces components.  The problem here is that RichFaces uses different skinning classes than jqueryUI.  What I'd LOVE to be able to do is to customize the RichFaces components that we are using to use a different class name.  That way, they'd just use the jqueryUI stuff.

According to the documentation, we can add the "styleClass" parameter to force the component to use a different class, and that works, but the RF class still remains.  This causes issues with our look and feel.

Second to this, we're using the inplace edit component and I can't seem to find a way to style the drop down that is generated once the  is clicked.

Does anyone have any ideas here?  I know that I could customize the RF theme to match our themeroller theme but that would make it much harder for us to support multiple themeroller themes.

As an aside, I've also read Chapter 6 of the RF manual, it doesn't seem to present an option that we can use (but maybe I've missed something):

[Chapter 6](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming-What_are_skins)

Comment: Ok, someone can close this out.  We switched to Primefaces to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.  We switched to Primefaces.