# Richfaces: How do I get complete control over the css

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

The project I'm working on has employed a designer to create the HTML/CSS. I want to drop the CSS files into our project, manipulate the HTML a little and have the application look like what the designer designed.

My problem is that richfaces is including it's own CSS files, which is affecting what the designer has produced.

I have turned off skinning with the org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning context parameter which has helped. However, I'm still getting css files such as datatable.ecss.jsf which is affecting the styling of my data tables.

I really don't want to have to add to our custom css overrides for every property that the richfaces css sets. And I certainly don't want to do what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455018/how-can-i-remove-the-css-classes-from-a-richfaces-component). I would have thought that this was a common use case, but I can't find any answers.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the css classes from RichFaces? What's the problem with that?

Comment: How would I go about removing the css classes?

Comment: Check here: [Remove Default CSS - For a specific component](https://community.jboss.org/message/40945)

Comment: I need to improve my googling skills! Thank you - add it as the answer to that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the RichFaces forum, you can disable all the RichFaces CSS for your project by setting the skin to "plain" or "null".

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Link of the info: [Remove Default CSS - For a specific component](https://community.jboss.org/message/40945)